# Making datastore and blobstore work transactional

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, transactions, google-cloud-datastore

I'm usnig Google App Engine with Java, and using Datastore via JPA.
I want to save profile image for each user:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private String userId;
    private String imageKey; // saves BlobKey.getKeyString()
    // ... other fields and getter/setter methods ...
}
```

If user wants to change their profile image, I (should) update imageKey field AND delete old image associated with old imageKey.

But, [the document of Blobstore for Python](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobinfoclass) says:

> Deleting a Blobstore value occurs separately from datastore transactions. If you call this method during a datastore transaction, it takes effect immediately, regardless of whether the transaction commits successfully or is retried.

This seems that I can't make updating imageKey and deleting old image as one atomic action, and it also would affect to Java.

This is my attempt to do this work:

```
public class Engine implements ServletContextListener {
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;
    private BlobstoreService blobstoreService;

    // Servlet will call getUser, modify returned object, and call updateUser with that object
    public User getUser(final String userId) throws EngineException {
        return doTransaction(new EngineFunc<User>() { // Utility method for create Entity manager and start transaction
            @Override
            public User run(EntityManager em) throws EngineException {
                return em.find(User.class, key);
            }
        });
    }

    public void updateUser(final User user) throws EngineException {
        doTransaction(new EngineFunc<Void>() {      
            @Override
            public Void run(EntityManager em) throws EngineException {
                em.merge(user);
                return null;
            }
        });
        user.purgeOldImages(blobstoreService);
    }

    // ... Other methods ...
}

public class User {
    @Transient
    private transient Set<String> oldImageList = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<>();

    public void setImageKey(String imageKey) {
        if (this.imageKey != null) {
            oldImageList.add(this.imageKey);
        }
        this.imageKey = imageKey;
        if (imageKey != null) {
            oldImageList.remove(imageKey);
        }
    }

    public void purgeOldImages(BlobstoreService blobService) {
        Set<BlobKey> toDelete = new HashSet<>();
        for (String s : oldImageList) {
            toDelete.add(new BlobKey(s));
            oldImageList.remove(s);
        }
        blobService.delete(toDelete.toArray(new BlobKey[0]));
    }

    // ... Other methods ...
}
```

I think this is neither "beautiful" nor correct code.
Is there the right way to do this?

Comment: Probably, you could enqueue a transactional task to delete the old key

Comment: @marcadian Thanks. [I tested you said](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/), and it works well. I changed purgeOldImages to put deletion job to queue, and call this function inside doTransaction.